# AS15: '403 error' for Supported Movie Quality call

Tags: camera, sony

When using the API I am getting 403 errors on the AS15. The call is listed when I request 'supportedApiList'.

```
Available Api List: {'id': 1, 'result': [['getMethodTypes', 'getAvailableApiList', 'setShootMode', 'getShootMode', 'getSupportedShootMode', 'getAvailableShootMode', 'setSteadyMode', 'getSteadyMode', 'getSupportedSteadyMode', 'getAvailableSteadyMode', 'setViewAngle', 'getViewAngle', 'getSupportedViewAngle', 'getAvailableViewAngle', 'setMovieQuality', 'getMovieQuality', 'getSupportedMovieQuality', 'getAvailableMovieQuality', 'startLiveview', 'stopLiveview', 'startMovieRec', 'stopMovieRec', 'startIntervalStillRec', 'stopIntervalStillRec', 'setCameraFunction', 'getCameraFunction', 'getSupportedCameraFunction', 'getAvailableCameraFunction', 'getStorageInformation', 'getApplicationInfo', 'getVersions', 'getEvent']]}
```

But then '403's when I actually call it...

```
Supported Movie Quality [ERROR] camera doesn't workHTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

There some discussion here:
[HDR-AS15: Supported Movie Quality [ERROR] camera doesn't work #9](https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api/issues/9)

Anyone have a suggestion how we can 'validate' the API List (which the camera gives is), so that we aren't getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the API reference documentation "Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API-Reference_v2.00.pdf" in the "Supported API groups for each compatible cameras" on Page 11.  That will tell you exactly which APIs are supported on which devices.  As you can see, Movie quality is not supported on the AS-15.